# Weld 2.3.5 Weird behaviour

Tags: wildfly-10, weld2

when `org.jboss.weld.construction.relaxed=true` property added to weld.properties file to WEB-INF directory of a war archive at the deployment this exception is thrown:

```
10:35:27,762 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test2: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./test2: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.JavaFlowLoaderHelper.loadFlows(JavaFlowLoaderHelper.java:84)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:303)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.weld.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:704)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:270)
    ... 20 more
```

which don't say anything meaningful i wonder if that this is expected behavior with bad exception message or a bug because application is working without weld.properties file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception isn't even coming from Weld, the problem is going to be elsewhere. I can also easily verify that the property can be used in this way (using the sample JSF numberguess app from Weld repository).

Comment: @Siliarus i can see that cause is com.sun.faces.application.JavaFlowLoaderHelper.loadFlows(JavaFlowLoaderHelper.java:84)

it looks like jsf problem isn't it but when you think https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/configure.html#relaxedConstruction

what property should do it shouldn't crash a deployment which working without it.

Also notice that there isn't even a one single class written by me in stack trace.

Comment: I find it very improbable that Weld-specific property causes NPE crash in JSF without a single Weld error line in the stack. The only case I can think of is proxy being created via this "relaxed construction" when there is a `@Inject` constructor, hence leaving some field not initialized... What Mojarra version are you using?

Comment: @Siliarus jsf-impl-2.2.13.SP1

Comment: This could potentially be a bug. If you can provide a reproducer app, please create a [Weld JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org) and we'll  take a closer look at it. It would require some debugging (hence the reproducer) but the suspicion is that JSF bootstrap might be too eager in calling `BM.getReference()`.

Comment: Alternatively, providing a debug log from app boot (you should be able to see `proxyInstantiator` there) + proxy dump of `FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension` ([here is how to do proxy dump](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.3.5.Final/en-US/html/configure.html#_debugging_generated_bytecode)) could help us see more. `FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension` is an extension in mojarra whose proxy Weld creates (and it contains no sensitive info from whatever app you have there) and inspecting that might help a great deal.

Comment: @Siliarus how can i set org.jboss.weld.proxy.dump property ?

Comment: There are three options - see docs http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_weld_configuration

Comment: @Siliarus https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2448